# PHP Submission Form to Email Check Boxes

Tags: php, mysql, email, forms

Hi guys im new to php and im making a submission form where people book online.

I have the form working fine but i want to add checkboxes for extras and then have  those extras noted in the confirmation emails sent to both the user and myself.

```
<tr>
    <td height="10" align="right" class="align_right">Deodoriser:&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="deodoriser" id="deodoriser" value="<?php echo $deodoriser?>"  onchange="checkFieldBack(this)"/>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Carpet Protector (5 litre):&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="carpet" id="carpet" value="<?php echo $carpet?>"  onchange="checkFieldBack(this)"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Carpet Repair Tools:&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="carpetrepair" id="carpetrepair" value="<?php echo $carpetrepair?>"  onchange="checkFieldBack(this)"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Furniture Moving Equipment:&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="furniture" id="furniture" value="<?php echo $furniture?>"  onchange="checkFieldBack(this)"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Furniture Tabs:&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="tabs" id="tabs" value="<?php echo $tabs?>"  onchange="checkFieldBack(this)"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Urine Decontamination Treatment:&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="urine" id="urine" value="<?php echo $urine?>"  onchange="checkFieldBack(this)"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would like to make these check boxes rather than text.
These are the variables

```
$deodoriser = (!empty($_REQUEST["deodoriser"]))?strip_tags(str_replace("'","`",$_REQUEST["deodoriser"])):'';
    $carpet = (!empty($_REQUEST["carpet"]))?strip_tags(str_replace("'","`",$_REQUEST["carpet"])):'';
    $carpetrepair = (!empty($_REQUEST["carpetrepair"]))?strip_tags(str_replace("'","`",$_REQUEST["carpetrepair"])):'';
    $furniture = (!empty($_REQUEST["furniture"]))?strip_tags(str_replace("'","`",$_REQUEST["furniture"])):'';
    $tabs = (!empty($_REQUEST["tabs"]))?strip_tags(str_replace("'","`",$_REQUEST["tabs"])):'';
    $urine = (!empty($_REQUEST["urine"]))?strip_tags(str_replace("'","`",$_REQUEST["urine"])):'';
```

This is the confirmation email

```
$message .="Name: ".$name;
$message .="<br />Email: ".$email;
$message .="<br />Phone: ".$phone;
$message .="<br />Quantity: ".$qty;
$message .="<br />Address: ".$comments;
$message .="<br />Drop off Time: ".$dropoff;
$message .="<br />Machine: ".$eventInf[0].;
$message .="<br />Deodoriser: ".$deodoriser;
$message .="<br />Carpet Protector: ".$carpet;
$message .="<br />Carpet Repair Tools: ".$carpetrepair;
$message .="<br />Furniture Moving Equipment: ".$furniture;
$message .="<br />Furniture Tabs: ".$tabs;
$message .="<br />Urine Decontamination Treatment: ".$urine;            
$message .="<br />Booking date: ".$eventInf[2]."<br />";
$message .="<br />Reservation Status: Not Confirmed<br />";
$message .="<br /><br />Kind Regards, <br /> ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']." Website";
```

Thanks for any help/advice i have looked through all similar questions here and tried for days to get it working and just cannot do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use checkboxes and store the values in an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" value="Deodoriser" />
<input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" value="Carpet" />
<input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" value="Furniture" />
```

Then loop through the $_POST['extras'] array to output the values

```
foreach($_POST['extras'] as $extra)
{
    $message .="<br />Extra: ".$extra;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create them in your HTML form as input type checkbox. All the checkboxes should have the same name, with square brackets at the end to denote a PHP array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="value"/>
```

When you submit the form, the values of all checked checkboxes will be available as an array  inside your GET or POST superglobal array under the name you gave it, so you can loop like this:

```
$options = $_GET['options'];
foreach ($options as $option) {
  // $option will now hold the "value" of the checkbox being processed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the input type to "checkbox".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `strip_tags(str_replace())` Just put in the string. e.g

```
$deodoriser = !empty($_REQUEST["deodoriser"]) ? 'Deodoriser' : '';
```

Along with setting `type="checkbox"` in your html.

And instead of `value=` you'll need to set `checked="checked"` in your HTML for each one if you want it pre-checked.

Comment: sorry i pasted the wrong one, i have changed all the check boxes to type checkbox already. will this email the results of the checkbox?

Comment: If the checkbox is checked, then it will be in the $_REQUEST array, and from there you can add it to the email. It doesn't look like you're including anything for the checkboxes in your email.

Comment: my mistake, i added the correct email as i pasted the wrong one.

Comment: Change the line to `$deodoriser = !empty($_REQUEST["deodoriser"]) ? 'Yes' : 'No';` and it'll work better with your email code.